# SQLite numColumns > 0 but fetchArray returns false

Tags: sqlite

I have this code

```
$res = $db->query("query...");
$res->numColumns(); // outputs: 14
$res->fetchArray(1); // outputs: false
$db->lastErrorMsg(); // outputs: unknown error
$db->lastErrorCode(); // outputs: 101 (SQLITE_DONE)
```

as you can see numColumns tells me there should be a result to my query, but then fetchArray returns false, and the error message and code are not really helpful.

**What could be happening that makes numColumns return a result > 0, but fetchArray return false?**

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting issue. The table i was trying to query contained syntax that the SQLite that comes with php was not enabled to read.

SQLite can be compiled using gcc with [several compiler flags](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) to enable/disable certain syntax.

In my case, the db i was reading from used nested parenthesis and the AND and NOT syntax. This is disabled by default and only allowed if SQLite is compiled with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS` flag.

If you have my same issue you can follow [this guide](https://datacadamia.com/lang/php/sqlite) to recompile your php SQLite version and update php to use it.